# Different cells between two data frames

Tags: r, set-difference

I need differences between two data frames. setdiff() gives me modyfied and new rows. But it shows a whole modified row, but I want only different cells. How to do this? I assume the number of columns is the same.

Input data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                  A = c(1, 2, 3),
                  B = c(1, 2, NA))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  B = c(1, 2, 3, NA))

newdata = setdiff(df2,df1) # don't give results as my expectation
```

As a result it should be such dataframe:

```
result <- data.frame(ID = c(3, 4),
                     A = c(NA, 4),
                    B = c(3, NA))
```

Column ID should be preserved and always should contain value.

Summary:

1. Output should contain only new, or modified rows from df2.
2. In modified rows should be displayed only modified or new cells.
3. Values in ID column should be displayed even they are not modified.

compare, compare_df? How to do this?

Comment: That result is not obvious. For example there is no A with an NA in the input, but there is in the output

Comment: NA in output for A column is because row with ID = 3, in column A has the same value in df1 and df2, so there is no change in cell [3,2]. If there is no change the value shouid be NA.

Comment: It appears you're applying different change logic to  ID, A and B. By your rules, result should be, ID NA,4 A NA 4, B 3 NA, applying the rules in order. Can be done, but not in one step.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in separate steps since you are applying different logic to different columns (ID vs A), but can't be achieved as a set of all columns.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
              A = c(1, 2, 3),
              B = c(1, 2, NA))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
              A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
              B = c(1, 2, 3, NA))
newdata = setdiff(df2,df1)
newdata
   ID A  B
1  1 1  1
2  2 2  2
3  3 3  3
4  4 4 NA
```

You can apply your logic to cols A & B, and not apply it to ID,

```
newdata$A[which(df2$A == df1$A)] <- NA

newdata$B[which(df2$B == df1$B)] <- NA

newdata
  ID  A  B
1  1 NA NA
2  2 NA NA
3  3 NA  3
4  4  4 NA

newdata[3:4,]
```

There are wizards far better than me that might opine, but I see no way to do this in one pass with the ID restriction.